# JavaScript to test for Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

What would be the shortest java-script to return 0 if not internet explorer, and 6-9 for which version it is?

Comment: @Matti Virkkunen http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710284

Comment: That's one old question you've got there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option: use IE's conditional comments:

```
<script>var IEversion</script>

<!--[if IE 8]>
<script>IEversion = 8</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: after googling strings within your answer I found http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512.aspx to be a much more valuable asset.

Answer (score 3):

With jQuery:

```
!$.browser.msie ? 0 : $.browser.version
```

Without jQuery:

```
!navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/) ? 0 : parseInt(navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE (\d+)/))
```

Comment: Please don't userAgent sniff. It will only lead to pain and suffering.

Comment: The jQuery way is definitely preferred.

Answer (score 0):

As above both implied, it all depends on your use and context.  In general, I'd say this is the best as it detects regardles of js turned on or off:

```
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script>IEversion = 8</script>    /*stylesheet, script, or whatever in there. */
<![endif]-->
```

[CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/) has the full list and basic overview

The jQuery by Radu if it's depending on jQuery, or another depending on your use.  And some frameworks/libraries have a method included, so double check there.